# C++ linker errors after declaring a template class

Tags: c++, resources, game-engine, sfml

I'm making some form of a resource manager for SFML objects and to prevent repeat code I thought I'd be clever and use templates. This however is not going well.

I've made a base class called `ResourceManager` which is a template class. It contains a map of strings as keys and unique pointers to type T as values. The class has a virtual destructor and a virtual load method which is used to load the different resources and it has two impelemented methods `get` and `erase` which are used to get or erase values from the map.

The class looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class ResourceManager
{
protected:
    std::string m_path;
    std::map< std::string , std::unique_ptr< T > >  resourceMap;
    virtual bool load(std::string &name) = 0;
public:
    ResourceManager(const std::string &path);
    virtual ~ResourceManager();
    T& get(const std::string &name);
    void erase(const std::string &name);
};

template<typename T>
ResourceManager<T>::ResourceManager(const std::string &path ) : m_path(path)
{}


template<typename T>
T& ResourceManager<T>::get(const std::string &name )
{
    if(resourceMap.empty() || resourceMap.find(name) == resourceMap.end())
    {
        if(!load(name))
        {
            std::cout << "Couldn't load resource " << name << std::endl;
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return *resourceMap.at(name);
}


template<typename T>
void ResourceManager<T>::erase(const std::string &name )
{
    resourceMap.erase(name);
}
```

and then there are separate SFML resource managers which inherit `ResourceManager` class and implement the load method. Here's an example of one of them:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML\Graphics\Font.hpp>

#include "ResourceManager.h"

class FontManager : public ResourceManager<sf::Font>
{
private:
    bool load(std::string &name);
public:
    FontManager(const std::string path);
    ~FontManager();
};

FontManager::FontManager(const std::string path ) : ResourceManager(path)
{}

FontManager::~FontManager()
{}

bool FontManager::load( std::string &name )
{
    resourceMap.insert(std::make_pair(name, std::unique_ptr<sf::Font>(new sf::Font)));
    return resourceMap.at(name)->loadFromFile(m_path + "\\" + name);
}
```

I thought this should work, however when building I get the following errors

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ResourceManager<class sf::Font>::ResourceManager<class sf::Font>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$ResourceManager@VFont@sf@@@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall FontManager::FontManager(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0FontManager@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) FontManager.obj

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall ResourceManager<class sf::Font>::~ResourceManager<class sf::Font>(void)" (??1?$ResourceManager@VFont@sf@@@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall FontManager::~FontManager(void)" (??1FontManager@@UAE@XZ)   FontManager.obj 

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class sf::Font & __thiscall ResourceManager<class sf::Font>::get(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?get@?$ResourceManager@VFont@sf@@@@QAEAAVFont@sf@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall GameStateIngame::draw(void)" (?draw@GameStateIngame@@UAEXXZ)   GameStateIngame.obj 

Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class sf::Font & __thiscall ResourceManager<class sf::Font>::get(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?get@?$ResourceManager@VFont@sf@@@@QAEAAVFont@sf@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)    GameStateIntro.obj

Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class sf::Font & __thiscall ResourceManager<class sf::Font>::get(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?get@?$ResourceManager@VFont@sf@@@@QAEAAVFont@sf@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)    GameStateMenu.obj
```

To explain a few more things that might cause confusion. Managers are declared as global variables inside namespaces and are located in Globals.h/Globals.cpp where they are initialized like this:

```
//Globals.h
namespace resource
{
    extern FontManager fontManager;
}

//Globals.cpp
namespace resource
{
    FontManager fontManager("res\\");
}
```

And are called inside GameState objects methods like this:

```
using namespace resource;
sf::Text text("Ingame State", fontManager.get("LeagueGothic-Regular.otf"), 70U);
```

These errors are not due to my faulty linking of SFML libraries because without my resource management classes SFML components work as intended. Something is wrong with my resource management classes and I can't figure out what. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to learn how to read the error messages from the compiler and the linker. In this case the linker is complaining:

> Error   2   error LNK2019: **unresolved** external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall **ResourceManager::~ResourceManager(void)**" (??1?$ResourceManager@VFont@sf@@@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall FontManager::~FontManager(void)" (??1FontManager@@UAE@XZ)   FontManager.obj

Where is the definition of your destructor?

The other errors are a bit harder to explain with the code that you posted. Is the definition of the `get` member function in the header that declares the template?

Comment: 1) I didn't define the virtual destructor, Isn't that the point of it? That I don't have to define virtual destructors of abstract classes but just implement derived class destructors, and in my FontManager class i have defined the destructor 
2) `get` method is declared in the header and implemented in the .cpp

Comment: @MrPlow 1) No, a virtual function needs to be defined unless it is *pure virtual*, a virtual destructor must be defined even if it is *pure virtual*. 2) Move the definitions of the functions to the header, if you want implicit instantiations of the template the compiler *must* see the function definitions

Comment: @dribeas I see. I implemented the destructor and moved the implementations of the `get` and `erase` methods to the header where the class is declared and now it works. I guess I'm still green when it comes to templates. 2) So whenever I'm making a template class I have to have the implementation in the header or I only have to do this if I have template methods inside that class? Also thanks a lot for helping me so quickly, I really appreciate it

Comment: @MrPlow: The general rule (as with most everything there are exceptions) is that templates should be defined in a header so that the compiler can use those definitions to generate code for the different specializations. The exceptions are very few, and I am inclined to disregard them as: *always* put the definitions in the header *unless you **know** otherwise*.